# Change href by data jquery fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

as it could change the href value of a bond of one data llamdad menu / content leave an example for me to understand:

By default we have this:

```
<a class="fancybox" href="#test1">Test 1</a>

<div id="test1" class="hide">
  <img alt="" src=".../images/480x360-1.jpg" />
</div>
```

What I seek to work is:

```
<span class="fancybox" data-menu="test1">Test 2</span>

<div data-content="test1" class="hide">
  <img alt="" src=".../images/480x360-1.jpg" />
</div>
```

**LINK:** http://jsfiddle.net/1co3hcpx/1/

Fancybox supports my nose if that way to make the effect.

If anyone can help me I would appreciate a lot. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

fancybox work based on href attribute (note: span should not have href) as a work around I've added href to the span tag 
 
you span should look like this:

```
<span class="fancybox" data-menu="test2" href="#test2">Test 2</span>
```

here is a working version 
http://jsfiddle.net/1co3hcpx/4/

Comment: if but the idea was based on the statement 2 does not modifcar at least in html but fancybox

Comment: if i were you i won't take the risk to modify fancybox it's better to hack your html